# Generate WebhookResponse containing quick replies using java dialogflowv2

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Can someone help me know how can i respond with quick replies to  webhookrequest using google dialogflow v2 java api. I want to sent quick replies while processing the fulfillment request